# How to find own YouTube videos not added to any playlist?

Tags: youtube

I would like to list all videos I've uploaded to YouTube, but not added to any playlist.
Is there any way to do it?
I looked at https://studio.youtube.com/, https://www.youtube.com/view_all_playlists?nv=1, but don't see such option/filter.

Comment: Perfect question. The negative vote it had was destructive (counting towards a ban; and obstructing bounties, thus prompting the asker to delete the question, which in turn would prevent it from getting answered).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own program to do that.
I advice using the [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for alternative answers, but here's one option:

You can use [JDownloader](https://jdownloader.org/download/index?s=lng_en): first crawl each playlist, *then* crawl all videos. Works also for other people's channels.

If Duplicate Manager ("Dupe Manager") and YouTube Crawl Duplicate Check ("YouTube Crawl Dupe Check") are enabled in *Settings -> Advanced Settings* (which they probably are by default) and JDownloader packages are named by YouTube playlists in *Settings -> Plugins -> YouTube* (which they probably are by default), then **the last package will contain only videos that are not in the previously crawled playlists**.

For playlists and channels with more than 100 videos, you'll need a workaround:

- One option is to scroll down to the end in the browser and copy the entire list of videos, instead of copying the link to the playlist or channel.

  If the link to the channel gets copied while copying videos from a playlist, you have to first disable the Clipboard Observer in JDownloader, add links for example via the *Add New Links* button at the bottom left, and delete the link to the channel before clicking *Continue*.
- Other workarounds are explained on the JDownloader forum.